# Trouble updating packages using Bower in ASP .NET vNext

Tags: asp.net, bower, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I have started `ASP .NET vNext` and I was going through several articles about using `bower` in `Visual Studio 2015` for managing client side libraries, it's pretty simple to use but I am having problems in updating the packages...

I am following [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-asp-net-5)

**bower.json**:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.3.2",
    "jquery": "1.4.1",
    "jquery-validation": "1.11.1",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.2",
    "hammer.js": "2.0.4",
    "bootstrap-touch-carousel": "0.8.0",
    "jquery-migrate-official": "^1.2.1",
    "bootstrap-hover-dropdown": "2.1.3",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "1.3.3",
    "jquery-cookie": "1.4.1",
    "jquery.uniform": "4.3.0",
    "blockui": "2.1.2",
    "font-awesome": "4.3.0"
},
```

[image]

The intellisense says that the package `blockui` has the latest stable version `2.1.2` but package manager log says:

```
bower blockui#2.1.2       ENORESTARGET No tag found that was able to satisfy 2.1.2
bower blockui#2.1.2         not-cached git://github.com/malsup/blockui.git#2.1.2
bower blockui#2.1.2            resolve git://github.com/malsup/blockui.git#2.1.
```

**Questions:**

- What does this mean? Is the intellisense picking up the wrong latest version?
- Is there any better way to update all client side packages like I used to do using `nuget package manager` ?

  ```
  update-package
  ```
- I read that for server-side packages ASP .NET vNext will use nuget packages but when I write any command in my `Package Manager Console` nothing happens

  ```
  update-package
  install-package entityframework
  ```

[image]

Comment: nuget is for server side dependencies, bower for client, bower is a package manager for client library such as js an css. Bower is intalled with npm

Comment: @aguafrommars I know that but I am having trouble using it, as I have shown in the question that bower is not updating the packages and the package manager console is not working either... How do I update all packages bower, nuget both?

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click the 'Bower' node under the 'Dependencies' node and choose 'Restore Packages'.  I often have to open the 'Task Runner Explorer' from 'View -> Other Windows' and run the 'bower' task from its context menu.  This will trigger a bower installation.

gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        bower: {
            install: {
                options: {
                    targetDir: "wwwroot/lib",
                    layout: "byComponent",
                    cleanTargetDir: false
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // This command registers the default task which will install bower packages into wwwroot/lib
    grunt.registerTask("default", ["bower:install"]);

    // The following line loads the grunt plugins.
    // This line needs to be at the end of this this file.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-bower-task");
};
```

package.json

```
{
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "name": "",
    "devDependencies": {
        "grunt": "0.4.5",
        "grunt-bower-task": "0.4.0"
    }
}
```

The packages should then show up in your wwwroot -> lib directory.

Check out bower's website for more details: http://bower.io/

Answer (score 0):

I just found that for (and for `font-awesome` package) IntelliSense advices non-existing version. That was 2.1.2, exactly like for your case, that is why I found your question.

I had re-checked real version, corrected it to existing one, and everything started to work.